# why isn't shared library fini function called when preloaded to dash?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, shared-libraries, ld-preload

I am on the latest Ubuntu Linux.

Here is a shared library with functions that are called when loading and unloading:

`shared.c`:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

void init() {
    open("init", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
}

void fini() {
    open("fini", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
}
```

and this is compiled with

`gcc -shared -fPIC -Wl,-init=init -Wl,-fini=fini shared.c -o shared.so`

and then I do this:

```
$ rm init fini
$ LD_PRELOAD=$PWD/shared.so  dash /dev/null
$ echo $?
0
$ ls init
init
$ ls fini
ls: cannot access 'fini': No such file or directory
```

So... loading function is called, but unloading function is not

If I replace `dash` with `bash` , both are called.

Using `__attribute__((destructor))` does not make a difference.

Why isn't the unloading function called for `dash`?

Added per Marco Bonelli's request:

```
$ file $(which dash)
/usr/bin/dash: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=f7ab02fc1b8ff61b41647c1e16ec9d95ba5de9f0, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped

$ ldd $(which dash)
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd931c0000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f6b19e84000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f6b1a0ec000)
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `file $(which dash)` and `ldd $(which dash)`? Just to understand what kind of executable it is.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli ??  it's `dash` - standard shell for the linux system

Comment: I know very well what `dash` is. What I don't know however is *what kind of ELF executable* of `dash` is installed on your system. This information would be relevant and could help answer your question.

Comment: @MaroBonelli oh I see, sorry, see the above added.  Do you not see the problem on your system?  I thought this must be happening on any recent Linux, and I just don't understand why.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like your `dash` is a dynamic ELF executable so in theory the loader should honor `LD_PRELOAD`... I'm assuming the output for `ldd $(shared.so)` is the same right? Check with `strace -f dash -c "> /dev/null"` and `strace -f dash -c "touch /dev/null"` if you see the `shared.so` file being opened/read by the loader in the two cases.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli  the loader absolutely honors `LD_PRELOAD` - I know that because lots of other routines get executed.  Just not the `fini` routine.

Comment: @Gilles 'SO- stop being evil'  Hi Gilles, could you possibly look at this question?  You have previously helped me with a shared library `fini` question.  But here I am stumped again. `strace` does not help, it just shows only `init` being created, but not `fini`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why isn't shared library fini function called when preloaded to dash?

Because dash calls `_exit` [here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/dash/dash.git/tree/src/trap.c#n406) which calls [exit_group](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/exit_group.2.html) syscall [here](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/_exit.c#L31) which terminates the program immediately.

Let's also do a small example:

```
# Makefile
all:
        gcc -shared -fPIC -Wl,-init=init -Wl,-fini=fini -Wl,-soname,shared.so shared.c -o shared.so
        gcc main.c -o main.out
        LD_PRELOAD=$(PWD)/shared.so ./main.out /dev/null

# main.c
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
        _exit(0);
}

# shared.c
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
void out(const char *str) {
        int fd = open("/dev/tty", O_WRONLY);
        write(fd, str, strlen(str));
        close(fd);
}
void init() {
        out("\nstart\n\n");
}
void fini() {
        out("\nstop\n\n");
}
```

On execution does not output stop:

```
$ make
gcc -shared -fPIC -Wl,-init=init -Wl,-fini=fini -Wl,-soname,shared.so shared.c -o shared.so
gcc main.c -o main.out
LD_PRELOAD=..../shared.so ./main.out /dev/null

start
```

Comment: wait... so, when I look at the official manpage documentation on `ld` and it talks about the `-fini` option, that is essentially worthless?  Because if the main program uses `_exit()` then the `-fini` function is ignored.  In other words, what's the point of `-fini` - I put some code in there that needs to run, but the main program can easily defeat that and my code will not run.

Comment: The point of `_exit` is to exit immediately. The point of `fini` is to add a finish function to exit. `the main program can easily defeat` The main program can call `abort()` or do a segmentation fault at any time.

Comment: so how do I ensure that my "finishing" code is always run after the main program exits to which my library is preloaded.  Is there no way??

Comment: yes I see.  I am screwed...  this is a showstopper for me if I can't rely to finish execution with my code.

Comment: `how do I ensure that my "finishing"` Wrap the program in a parent program. `bash -c 'trap "echo finishing task" EXIT; ./yourprogram'`. Use process managers, service orchestrators - `systemd` or `systemd-run`, etc.

Comment: yes but see... I can't "wrap" - I write the `.so` library.  The customer controls the main program, I can't tell them to wrap it or anything.  I must attach to them and do my thing, part of which has to run after the main program finishes, in any way .

Comment: I only have an idea to ask that question on SO ;) . I think you can't, kernel can kill you at any time, even OOM kill. Usually if you interface with hardware, there is like a "reset" functionality, and I typically wrap that in a shell script. Or there is a reset on strartup. Would be nice to explain what _exactly_ are interfacing with that you need to run a fini function.

Comment: thank you Kamil, I appreciate, no it's clear for me, I have to rewrite my code to not use `-fini` this is gonna be painful but must be done, oh well

Answer (score 1):

I should have put this as a comment, but I put it as an answer for formatting purposes.

The problem is not about the difference between `redirection` and `touch`, because in your dash/touch run, shared.so has been loaded twice, once for dash, once for touch.
`fini` fired only with `touch`.

You can see the diffrence with these two runs :

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=$PWD/shared.so  dash  /dev/null
# fini is not called
$ LD_PRELOAD=$PWD/shared.so  touch /dev/null
# fini is called
```

So this has something to do with `dash`.

Hope this provide more materials for your investigation.

Comment: thank you for pointing this out, I am going to revise and simplify the question according to your observation